# ListAdapter getView with wrong value for position

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, listadapter

This question addresses fundamentally the same problem as [Old Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547472/baseadapters-getview-getting-wrong-position) 
Its re-written, because the code is much more readable, and i changed the adapter from a BaseAdapter extension to a ListAdapter interface implementation (wich was pointless).

I have this weird problem with position variable inside getView method of the adapter. 4 of those 6 different view types, got a button inside them. That button sends a message to a service (provoking some async stuff on the service), and within an indefinite amount of time after, this adapter gets a notifyDataSetChanged() provoked by the service.

The problem shows when i spam the button that sends the message. If i spam it fast enough, the wrong data will be sent to the service. I think the problem is that during the spam, i will hit the button during a notifyDataSetChanged(), because if i comment that call on the methods that the service is using, this inconsistency wont happen. Also if i don't spam the button (like a 1 s delay between taps), it will work correctly.

The weird thing is that within the getView method, a getItem(position) call, will return different items. It will return the correct item to build the view itself, but may return the wrong item to a onClickListener of a button within the view.

Heres the full adapter class:

```
public class ListViewFolderAdapter implements ListAdapter{

    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 6;

    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<ListViewDataItem> data = null;
    private String[] selected;
    private MainPagerAdapter mainPagerAdapter;
    private int listPosition;
    private String dirName;

    private final DataSetObservable mDataSetObservable;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public ListViewFolderAdapter(MainActivity mActivity, MainPagerAdapter mainPagerAdapter, int listPosition, 
            String dirName, ArrayList<ListViewDataItem> data) {
        this.mActivity=mActivity;
        this.mainPagerAdapter = mainPagerAdapter;
        this.listPosition = listPosition;
        this.data = data;
        this.dirName=dirName;
        this.inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        this.mDataSetObservable = new DataSetObservable();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        StandardFolderViewHolder standardFolderViewHolder = null;
        StandardFileViewHolder standardFileViewHolder = null;
        MusicFileStoppedViewHolder musicFileStoppedHolder = null;
        MusicFilePlayingViewHolder musicFilePlayingHolder = null;
        MusicFolderStoppedViewHolder musicFolderStoppedHolder = null;
        MusicFolderPlayingViewHolder musicFolderPlayingHolder = null;

        switch(getItemViewType(position)) {
        case Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.STANDARD_DIRECTORY:
            if(row == null) {
                standardFolderViewHolder = new StandardFolderViewHolder();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_standard_folder_row, parent, false);
                standardFolderViewHolder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.filetype_icon);
                standardFolderViewHolder.tempTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listview_mixed_folder_row_test_tv);
                row.setTag(standardFolderViewHolder);
            }
            else {
                standardFolderViewHolder = (StandardFolderViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            standardFolderViewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).getDrawable());
            standardFolderViewHolder.tempTV.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            standardFolderViewHolder.tempTV.setSelected(true);
            break;
        case Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.STANDARD_FILE:
            if(row == null) {
                standardFileViewHolder = new StandardFileViewHolder();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_standard_folder_row, parent, false);
                standardFileViewHolder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.filetype_icon);
                standardFileViewHolder.tempTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listview_mixed_folder_row_test_tv);
                row.setTag(standardFileViewHolder);
            }
            else {
                standardFileViewHolder = (StandardFileViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            standardFileViewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).getDrawable());
            standardFileViewHolder.tempTV.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            standardFileViewHolder.tempTV.setSelected(true);
            break;
        case Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_DIRECTORY_PLAYING_STATE:
            if(row == null) {
                musicFolderPlayingHolder = new MusicFolderPlayingViewHolder();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_music_folder_playing_row, parent, false);
                musicFolderPlayingHolder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.filetype_icon);
                musicFolderPlayingHolder.songName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_title_tv);
                musicFolderPlayingHolder.playButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.row_play_button);
                musicFolderPlayingHolder.durationTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_duration_tv);
                musicFolderPlayingHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.folder_progress_bar);
                row.setTag(musicFolderPlayingHolder);
            }
            else {
                musicFolderPlayingHolder = (MusicFolderPlayingViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).getDrawable());
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.songName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.songName.setSelected(true);
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.durationTV.setText(mActivity.formattedMillis(getItem(position).getDuration()));
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.progressBar.setMax(getItem(position).getDuration());
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.progressBar.setProgress(getItem(position).getProgress()); 
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.playButton.setTag(getItem(position));
            musicFolderPlayingHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
            break;
        case Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_DIRECTORY_STOPPED_STATE:
            if(row == null) {
                musicFolderStoppedHolder = new MusicFolderStoppedViewHolder();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_music_folder_stopped_row, parent, false);
                musicFolderStoppedHolder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.filetype_icon);
                musicFolderStoppedHolder.songName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_title_tv);
                musicFolderStoppedHolder.playButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.row_play_button);
                musicFolderStoppedHolder.durationTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_duration_tv);
                row.setTag(musicFolderStoppedHolder);
            }
            else {
                musicFolderStoppedHolder = (MusicFolderStoppedViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            musicFolderStoppedHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).getDrawable());
            musicFolderStoppedHolder.songName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            musicFolderStoppedHolder.songName.setSelected(true);
            musicFolderStoppedHolder.durationTV.setText(mActivity.formattedMillis(getItem(position).getDuration()));
            musicFolderStoppedHolder.playButton.setTag(getItem(position));
            musicFolderStoppedHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());

            break;
        case Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_FILE_PLAYING_STATE:
            if(row == null) {
                musicFilePlayingHolder = new MusicFilePlayingViewHolder();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_music_file_playing_row, parent, false);
                musicFilePlayingHolder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.filetype_icon);
                musicFilePlayingHolder.songName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_title_tv);
                musicFilePlayingHolder.playButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.music_file_playing_row_play_button);
                musicFilePlayingHolder.durationTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_duration_tv);
                musicFilePlayingHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.folder_progress_bar);
                row.setTag(musicFilePlayingHolder);
            }
            else {
                musicFilePlayingHolder = (MusicFilePlayingViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            musicFilePlayingHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).getDrawable());
            musicFilePlayingHolder.songName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            musicFilePlayingHolder.songName.setSelected(true);
            musicFilePlayingHolder.durationTV.setText(mActivity.formattedMillis(getItem(position).getDuration()));
            musicFilePlayingHolder.progressBar.setMax(getItem(position).getDuration());
            musicFilePlayingHolder.progressBar.setProgress(getItem(position).getProgress());
            musicFilePlayingHolder.playButton.setTag(getItem(position));
            musicFilePlayingHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
            break;
        case Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_FILE_STOPPED_STATE:
            if(row == null) {
                musicFileStoppedHolder = new MusicFileStoppedViewHolder();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_music_file_stopped_row, parent, false);
                musicFileStoppedHolder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.filetype_icon);
                musicFileStoppedHolder.songName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_title_tv);
                musicFileStoppedHolder.playButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.music_file_stopped_row_play_button);
                musicFileStoppedHolder.durationTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_duration_tv);

                row.setTag(musicFileStoppedHolder);
            }
            else {
                musicFileStoppedHolder = (MusicFileStoppedViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            musicFileStoppedHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).getDrawable());
            musicFileStoppedHolder.songName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            musicFileStoppedHolder.songName.setSelected(true);
            musicFileStoppedHolder.durationTV.setText(mActivity.formattedMillis(getItem(position).getDuration()));
            musicFileStoppedHolder.playButton.setTag(getItem(position));
            musicFileStoppedHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
            break;
        }

        if(!getItem(position).wasAnimatedIn()) {
            row.startAnimation(getItem(position).getGoingIn());
        }
        else if (!getItem(position).wasAnimatedOut()) {
            Animation outAnim = getItem(position).getGoingOut();
            outAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    data.remove(getItem(position));
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            });
            row.startAnimation(outAnim);
        }   
        Log.e("getView" + getItem(position).getName(), "pos: " + position);
        return row;
    }

    public void insert(ListViewDataItem object, int index) {
        data.set(index, object);
        object.setAnimatedInFalse();
    }

    public void removeWithAnimation(String fileName) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if(data.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(fileName) == 0) {
                getItem(i).setAnimatedOutFalse();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                selectItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int itemPosition) {
        mainPagerAdapter.setSelectedItemInList(listPosition, itemPosition);
    }

    static class StandardFolderViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView tempTV;
        TextView tempTV2;
    }

    static class StandardFileViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView tempTV;
        TextView tempTV2;
    }

    static class MusicFileStoppedViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView songName;
        Button playButton;
        TextView durationTV;
    }

    static class MusicFilePlayingViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView songName;
        Button playButton;
        TextView durationTV;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }

    static class MusicFolderStoppedViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView songName;
        Button playButton;
        TextView durationTV;
    }

    static class MusicFolderPlayingViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView songName;
        Button playButton;
        TextView durationTV;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }

    void setSelectedPosition(String[] selection) {
        this.selected=selection;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public String[] getSelectedPosition() {
        return this.selected;
    }

    public String getDirName() {
        return this.dirName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListViewDataItem getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * must return 0 <= int < getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getType();
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return getCount() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        mDataSetObservable.registerObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        mDataSetObservable.unregisterObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    public void updateTypeAndDuration(int position, int type, int duration) {
        ListViewDataItem lvDataItem = getItem(position);
        lvDataItem.setType(type);
        lvDataItem.setDuration(duration);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateProgressInFile(int positionInPage, int maxProgress, int progress) {
        if(positionInPage < getCount()) {
            ListViewDataItem lvDataItem = getItem(positionInPage);
            lvDataItem.setDuration(maxProgress);
            lvDataItem.setProgress(progress);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void activatePlayingState(int positionInPage) {
        if(positionInPage < getCount()) {
            ListViewDataItem lvDataItem = getItem(positionInPage);
            if(lvDataItem.getType() == Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_DIRECTORY_STOPPED_STATE) {
                lvDataItem.setType(Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_DIRECTORY_PLAYING_STATE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(lvDataItem.getType() == Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_FILE_STOPPED_STATE) {
                lvDataItem.setType(Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_FILE_PLAYING_STATE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearPlayState() {
        boolean stateChanged = false;
        for(ListViewDataItem lvDataItem : data) {
            if(lvDataItem.getType() == Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_DIRECTORY_PLAYING_STATE) {
                lvDataItem.setType(Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_DIRECTORY_STOPPED_STATE);
                stateChanged = true;
            }
            else if(lvDataItem.getType() == Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_FILE_PLAYING_STATE) {
                lvDataItem.setType(Constants.MEDIA_FILE.TYPE.MUSIC_FILE_STOPPED_STATE);
                stateChanged = true;
            }
        }
        if(stateChanged) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Clicked", (String)((ListViewDataItem)v.getTag()).getName());
            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putString(Constants.BUNDLE_KEYS.PLAY_FILES, (String)((ListViewDataItem)v.getTag()).getPath());
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, Constants.OP_CODE.PLAY_FILES);
            message.setData(bun);
            try {
                mActivity.mService.send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException re) {
                re.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a LogCat dump of me spamming the button inside the view at position 1, filename being 02 Maniac.flac

```
10-24 11:39:06.929: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:06.949: E/TRYING TO PLAY(21489): /mnt/sdcard/Music/Caravan Palace/Caravan Palace - Panic (2012) FLAC/02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:06.949: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:07.049: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:07.169: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:07.169: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:07.169: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:07.179: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:07.179: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:07.179: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:07.239: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:07.259: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:07.269: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:07.269: E/TRYING TO PLAY(21489): /mnt/sdcard/Music/Caravan Palace/Caravan Palace - Panic (2012) FLAC/02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:07.289: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:07.299: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:07.329: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:07.339: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:07.339: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:07.409: W/MediaPlayer(21489): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
10-24 11:39:07.419: E/TRYING TO PLAY(21489): /mnt/sdcard/Music/Caravan Palace/Caravan Palace - Panic (2012) FLAC/02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:07.489: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:07.499: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:07.499: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:07.519: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:07.519: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:07.539: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:07.599: E/Clicked(21489): 05 Rock it for me.flac
10-24 11:39:07.619: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:07.629: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:07.629: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:07.639: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:07.639: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:07.639: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:07.699: E/Clicked(21489): 06 Clash.flac
10-24 11:39:07.709: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:07.789: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:07.799: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:07.809: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:07.809: E/TRYING TO PLAY(21489): /mnt/sdcard/Music/Caravan Palace/Caravan Palace - Panic (2012) FLAC/05 Rock it for me.flac
10-24 11:39:07.829: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:07.859: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:07.869: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:08.039: D/dalvikvm(21489): GC_CONCURRENT freed 185K, 45% free 3396K/6087K, external 327K/839K, paused 5ms+6ms
10-24 11:39:08.049: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:08.049: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:08.059: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:08.059: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:08.069: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:08.069: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:08.129: E/Clicked(21489): 06 Clash.flac
10-24 11:39:08.129: E/Clicked(21489): 06 Clash.flac
10-24 11:39:08.159: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
10-24 11:39:08.239: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:08.249: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:08.259: E/TRYING TO PLAY(21489): /mnt/sdcard/Music/Caravan Palace/Caravan Palace - Panic (2012) FLAC/06 Clash.flac
10-24 11:39:08.259: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:08.259: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:08.289: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:08.319: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
10-24 11:39:08.409: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
10-24 11:39:08.419: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
10-24 11:39:08.419: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
10-24 11:39:08.419: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
10-24 11:39:08.429: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
10-24 11:39:08.429: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
```

You can see the getView mehod being correctly called with the right position for every item:

```
 10-24 11:39:06.949: E/getView 01 Queens.flac(21489): pos: 0
    10-24 11:39:07.049: E/getView 02 Maniac.flac(21489): pos: 1
    10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 03 The dirty side of the street.flac(21489): pos: 2
    10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 04 12 June 3049.flac(21489): pos: 3
    10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 05 Rock it for me.flac(21489): pos: 4
    10-24 11:39:07.069: E/getView 06 Clash.flac(21489): pos: 5
```

But then on the button clicks, the getItem method is returning wrong items sometime (recall im spamming 02 Maniac.flac)

```
 10-24 11:39:07.699: E/Clicked(21489): 06 Clash.flac
    10-24 11:39:07.709: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
```

--

```
10-24 11:39:07.599: E/Clicked(21489): 05 Rock it for me.flac
```

--

```
10-24 11:39:08.129: E/Clicked(21489): 06 Clash.flac
    10-24 11:39:08.129: E/Clicked(21489): 06 Clash.flac
    10-24 11:39:08.159: E/Clicked(21489): 02 Maniac.flac
```

Comment: Have you seen this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have something to do with recycling views...?

I have a similar problem in a listview, but I haven't found a good solution, I keep looking for it.

As my listview will never contain more than 15 rows i'm using a very unnefective solution, not to recycle my rows, while i'm researching how to fix the problem.

[ListView recycling view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313042/listview-recycling-view)

Comment: Hello. As i finished posting this question, i started thinking this really looks like a thread synch problem on the view recycling mechanism. Im almost done with implementing an "override" for that view recycling mechanism based on @buptcoder 's answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453379/android-list-adapter-returns-wrong-position-in-getview. Will say how it worked when im done, brb.

Comment: You were right, now without using the recicling mechanism, there is no inconsistencies on the position. I am holding my views inside a SparseArray<View> viewCache;, and i check them against the ArrayList<ListViewDataItem> data inside getView method. So if the viewCache is null at the current position, or if the item there is of the wrong type, i infalte the right view type and fill it with the right data. But this has very poor performance at the moment, because im changing the view types too frequently. I will work further on it, but view recycling was the problem idd. Thx :)

Comment: I like your idea! I think i'll try it up! Thanks

Comment: Btw, i found that what was slowing this down was that i was using viewCache.put(position,row); everytime the getView was called. So i moved the viewCache.put to only where was the case that viewCache.get(position) returned null. The speed now is as good as with a standard adapter implementation. Anyway this is a bad ideia for me because if i have lists with lots of elements, i will be hogging a lot of memory. But maybe its good enough if your lists have few elements.